# How to Animate UITextField Text Content Position

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, uiviewanimation

I subclassed `UITextField` and assigned an icon (exclamation mark at the image) to its `leftView` and animated its constraints. Similarly, I created an `errorLabel` (the one with 'Hello World' text at the image) and animated it with the icon when user submits content.

[image]

My problem is when `errorLabel` animates up, I change text content's (someemail@email.com) position with:

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: (leftView?.width ?? 0) + 8, bottom: leftView?.width > 0 ? 12 : 0, right: 0))
}
```

(So I move text content 12 points up) But right now this change happens without an animation and text content just go up or down abruptly. Is there a way to smoothly animate it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if the inset is an 'animateable' property. I'd do it changing the label's constraints. I also wouldn't recommend animating the text that the user has entered.

Comment: How about the exclamation mark appears on the right end? And the warning label appears below the line? Or on tapping the exclamation?

Comment: Hey Rakesha, thanks for the recommendations - they make sense. I will give them a try!